# How to do SOS Integration on iOS12

Tags: ios, ios12

I am developing an application on women safety.
I need help from an expert who is in touch with the latest Apple iOS release. Regarding what Apple restrict and What not?

**Below are the following feature:**

- **SMS** - Can we send SMS to someone without presenting MFMessageComposeViewController?
- **Call** - Call we call someone without prompting call dialer?
- **Video** - Can we open camera record video and save it without any user action automatically?
- **Picture** - Can we open camera capture picture and save it without any user action automatically?
- **Location** - Can we capture location. without user action?
- **Email** - Can we send Email to someone without presenting EmailComposeViewController?

**Note**: User has granted permission of all the above feature.
On clicking a button all the above action should perform.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"No" is the answer to all of your questions except for Location - if the user granted location permissions and the device has location services on then the app can always get the current locations and do what it needs to do with it (for example you can attach your location data to an outgoing iMessage, etc). Additionally, while you can't send an email the way you describe - you could post data to a server/resource that then would compose and send out the email.